# Get SELECT field type having the field name with MariaDB C++ connector

Tags: c++, mariadb

I have a MariaDB select, which is treated in a generic C++ class.
I need to get the select field type to do a treatment in case it is FLOAT or DOUBLE, but all fields are handled by the same function.
An example:

```
std::string sqlwrap::operator [] (std::string field_name)
{
    nflog ();
    if (!_res || _type == sql_void || _type == sql_invalid)
        return "";

    std::string res;
    try {
        res = _store->getString(field_name);
    } catch (sql::SQLException & e) {
        logp (sys::e_debug, "SQL exception: "
              << e.what());
    }
    return res;
}
```

In this function I have to check if it is a FLOAT and then change '.' (decimal place) by ',' (decimal place in some european countries).

That could be something in the line...

```
std::string sqlwrap::operator [] (std::string field_name)
{
    nflog ();
    if (!_res || _type == sql_void || _type == sql_invalid)
        return "";

    std::string res;
    try {
        res = _store->getString(field_name);
        switch (_store->getFieldType(field_name)) {
            case DOUBLE:
                res = change_dots_by_comma(res);
                break;
            default:
        }
    } catch (sql::SQLException & e) {
        logp (sys::e_debug, "SQL exception: "
              << e.what());
    }
    return res;
}
```

I know there is the FORMAT function, but I would like to know if I can get the field type with the field name with the MariaDB C++ connector.
I don't want to use FORMAT in the select.

Answer (score 0):

Use the appropriate "Locale" to get "decimal point", "thousands separator", etc.  Note also that there is an optional locale parameter in MariaDB's `FORMAT()`.

For schema info about a column:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_schema = "database_name"
      AND table_name = "table_name"
      AND column_name = "column_name"
```

An example of a FLOAT and a DECIMAL:

```
CREATE TABLE `dec184` (
  `d` decimal(18,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `d2` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL,
  `dx` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `dv` float DEFAULT NULL
)
```

from the query:

```
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           TABLE_CATALOG: def
            TABLE_SCHEMA: try
              TABLE_NAME: dec184
             COLUMN_NAME: d2
        ORDINAL_POSITION: 2
          COLUMN_DEFAULT: NULL
             IS_NULLABLE: NO
               DATA_TYPE: decimal
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH: NULL
  CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH: NULL
       NUMERIC_PRECISION: 18
           NUMERIC_SCALE: 4
      DATETIME_PRECISION: NULL
      CHARACTER_SET_NAME: NULL
          COLLATION_NAME: NULL
             COLUMN_TYPE: decimal(18,4)
              COLUMN_KEY: 
                   EXTRA: 
              PRIVILEGES: select,insert,update,references
          COLUMN_COMMENT: 
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           TABLE_CATALOG: def
            TABLE_SCHEMA: try
              TABLE_NAME: dec184
             COLUMN_NAME: dx
        ORDINAL_POSITION: 3
          COLUMN_DEFAULT: NULL
             IS_NULLABLE: YES
               DATA_TYPE: float
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH: NULL
  CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH: NULL
       NUMERIC_PRECISION: 12
           NUMERIC_SCALE: NULL
      DATETIME_PRECISION: NULL
      CHARACTER_SET_NAME: NULL
          COLLATION_NAME: NULL
             COLUMN_TYPE: float
              COLUMN_KEY: 
                   EXTRA: 
              PRIVILEGES: select,insert,update,references
          COLUMN_COMMENT:
```

Comment: I'm asking expressly for a way to know the field type having the field name. May be I should be more precise and remark using the MariaDB C++ library.